# How can I use cPanel to change move a domain to a subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I have a site hosted on Namecheap.

I need to move the whole site to a sub-domain on the same domain. I know I can do that through Cpanel on name cheap but am not sure how and what the best way to do this easily and safely.

Could someone provide me some guidance as how to get this started?

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the site is large, using ssh might be better. If you have ssh access you can simply use ssh to zip the files in to chunks and move it into the sub domain.
However if it's not large, you can simply create your sub domain on cpanel, zip your site files on file manager then move to the sub domain and unzip.

N:B This advice is based on the assumption that the site is not in production otherwise you need to notify appropriate quarters of downtime period.